# UIScrollView does not scroll in landscape mode - test code and screenshots attached

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, rotation

In Xcode 5.0.2 I have created [a universal app](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/Scroll) and dragged a `UIScrollView` and an `UIImageView` (with its "View Mode" changed to "Top Left") into the iPhone and iPad storyboards (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqaTz.png)):

[image: xcode screenshot]

In the attempt to make the `UIScrollView` fill the whole screen I've added 4 constraints (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAzN.png)):

[image: xcode screenshot]

Then in the [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/ViewController.m) I am trying to:

1. Load the `board.png` (copyright Wikipedia Commons, Denelson83)
2. Give the `UIImageView` same dimensions as `board.png`
3. Set the `contentSize` of the `UIScrollView` to same size

Here the source code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
    NSLog(@"%s: (%f x %f)", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    _imageView.image = img;
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.bounds.size;
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];

    // fruitless attempt to solve the rotation problem
    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.bounds.size;
}
```

Here the output:

```
Scroll[3464:70b] -[ViewController viewDidLoad]: (1000.000000 x 961.500000)
```

This kind of works, but has 2 problems:

**Problem 1:**

When I rotate the iPhone or iPad simulators (by pressing Cmd - Left Arrow) - the image scrolling stops working:

[image: iphone 3.5 screenshot]

[image: ipad screenshot]

**Problem 2:**

In the portrait mode the scrolling works, but I can't reach the bottom right corner:

[image: iphone 4 screenshot]

**UPDATE 1:**

I've tried iphonic's suggestion (thanks!) and I see the `deviceOrientationDidChange` selector being called, but the app still doesn't scroll:

```
Scroll[702:70b] -[ViewController viewDidLoad]: image size = {1000, 961.5}
Scroll[702:70b] -[ViewController deviceOrientationDidChange:]: view size = {1000, 961.5}
Scroll[702:70b] -[ViewController deviceOrientationDidChange:]: view size = {1000, 961.5}
Scroll[702:70b] -[ViewController deviceOrientationDidChange:]: view size = {1000, 961.5}
```

(I am using `_imageView.image.size` though, since `_imageView.size` is defined as 100 x 100 in my sotryboards):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
    NSLog(@"%s: image size = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGSize(img.size));
    _imageView.image = img;
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector: @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:)
         name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object: nil];
}

-(void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification

{
    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.image.size;
    NSLog(@"%s: view size = %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, NSStringFromCGSize(_imageView.image.size));
}
```

Comment: It seems `ContentSize` problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the code for Orientation and viewDidLayoutSubviews
2. Mention UIScrollView contentSize in viewDidLoad Method
3. Uncheck AutoResizeSubview of UIScrollView = NO in XIB under Drawing section and Check Clip SubViews.

Refer to https://github.com/jayaprada-behera/ScrollViewOrientation

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //set uiscrollview.autoresizeSubview = NO; in xib
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board.png"];
    imageView_.image = img;

    imageView_.frame = CGRectMake(imageScrollView.frame.origin.x, imageScrollView.frame.origin.y, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    imageScrollView.contentSize = imageView_.bounds.size;
}
```

It will work.

Comment: Thank you. Why is setting "Clip Subviews" necessary?

Comment: Clip Subviews for the scroll view. This will not allow the subviews (here imageview)to go beyond the bound of ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to add.

1. Don't use `bounds`, because in rotation the frame is changing, and you need to get changed values, with `bounds` values never changes.
2. There is some problem with your `AutoLayout` settings, try turn it off.
3. Remove all the code used to set contentSize. Just use the code below.

   ```
   -(void)viewDidLoad
     {
       [super viewDidLoad];

       UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
       NSLog(@"%s: (%f x %f)", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, img.size.width, img.size.height);
       _imageView.image = img;
       _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

       //Handles rotation notifications
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector: @selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil]; 
   }



   -(void)deviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification

   {
       _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.frame.size;

       NSLog(@"Size = %@",NSStringFromCGSize(_imageView.frame.size));
   }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work for me (can't scroll at all). And isn't `origin` point the only difference between `bounds` and `frame`?

Comment: I get `view size = {100, 100}` because UIImageView size in the storyboard is 100 x 100... but how to set it to the image size instead?

Comment: You can interchange the height and width values on rotation. Use UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]; And you get imageview size 100,100 due to wrong AutoLayout, I have checked your code. turn off the autolayout it will work..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would make an image scroll.

1. Pin the edges of the scroll view to the parent view.
2. Pin the edges of the image to the scroll view.
3. Set the image's width and height constraints explicitly.
4. Build and run.

With Step 1, you position the scroll view with respect to the screen and then with Steps 2 and 3 you actually define how big the image is going to be and how relative to the scroll view it should be positioned. If this is done, content size of the scroll is calculated automatically and doesn't have to be explicitly handled even for rotation changes.

Comment: Yes. Similar to how you have done for your scroll view. Storyboard/Xib -> Select element -> Add your constraints.

Comment: What do you please mean by "pin the edges"? Haven't I done it here? http://i.stack.imgur.com/2CAzN.png (sorry, my edited comment slipped down)

Comment: The idea here is to make sure that the image is pinned to the scrollview too. So, with the image, I will update 6 constraints probably. 4 for the edges and a width and a height.

Answer (score 1):

In your source code Auto layout is enabled. I am not much aware on setting constraint in case of dynamic imageView size But if you want to do it without constraint then turn off Autolayout  in Mainstoryboard. And modify following method by this,

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
    NSLog(@"%s: (%f x %f)", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    _imageView.image = img;
    _imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.bounds.size;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as an iOS newbie I don't understand the auto layout suggestions - why should I turn it off? Is it bad for my type of app?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're are instantiating the image view in storyboard, its layout is dictated by Auto Layout, no matter what you do in code. Therefore, setting the image view's frame in code accomplishes nothing.

Although you haven't configured any constraints for the image view explicitly (as far as I can tell), Xcode has installed implicit constraints. These constraints are probably not what you want.

Also, you cannot set the scroll view's `contentSize` explicitly. Instead, the `contentSize` is determined automatically by the size of the image view.

You may wish to review Apple's Technical Note before proceeding: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

My own solution:

In Interface Builder I have assigned width and height to the `UIImageView` and set its "View Mode" to "Bottom" (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffTpw.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

The following code in [ViewController.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/Scroll/Scroll/ViewController.m) has sufficed (no rotation detection is necessary):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"board"];
    _imageView.image = img;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    _scrollView.contentSize = _imageView.bounds.size;
}
```